# How to connect from one Pod to another using Local IP Address or Pod's host name

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks

There are two deployments: **deployment-A** and **deployment-B** both running on a same cluster. Both deployments are running a single pod with a single container.

The deployment-A's **Pod-A**'s internal IP address is: 172.31.10.211. And it is exposed via port 50000.

```
podIP: 172.31.10.211
containerPort: 50000
```

I want to connect to this **Pod-A** from **Pod-B** that is running on *deployment-B*.

But it seems **Pod-A** is not reachable from **Pod-B**. Should I create a Service, like a LoadBalancer, for the **deployment-A** in order to connect to **Pod-A** via LoadBalancer's public IP address? Would it be possible to use the Pod-A's Local IP instead or Pod-A's hostname?

Is there anything that could be done to make the Pods communicate using Local IPs?

Comment: A [ClusterIP-type service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) provides a DNS name that can be reached by all pods, but only from inside the cluster.  You usually don't connect directly to pods and you usually don't deal directly in IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I can reach the Pod from another VM. This VM runs outside of the Cluster (standalone VM), it is on the same VPC. I can reach the Pod using the Pod's local IP address, such as `172.31.10.211` or using Deployment's Load Balancer's DNS name such as `63096.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com`. But I can't find the way to reach a Pod from another Pod while both Pods are running inside the same cluster. What should I be using to make one Pod to connect to another Pod, the DNS name `63096.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: The [cluster-internal DNS name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) of the Service, something like `servicename.namespacename.svc.cluster.local`.  (Every LoadBalancer service is a NodePort service is a ClusterIP service.)  You shouldn't be able to access the pod-local IP address from outside the cluster.

Comment: The `kubectl get service deployment-A-load-balancer` gives me: `CLUSTER-IP: 10.100.237.237` and `EXTERNAL-IP: 10.100.237.237` and `EXTERNAL-IP: 63096.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com` and `PORT(S): 50000:30020/TC`.

Comment: Should I be using the `CLUSTER-IP` address `10.100.237.237` to connect from Pod-B to the Pod-A? Or should I be using the `EXTERNAL-IP` address `63096.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: No, you should use the DNS name `deployment-A-load-balancer` as a host name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a service for each deployment. You should be able connect the pod  through the service. Service type can be clusterIP or nodeport or load balancer. All of them should work

Comment: I am able to connect to the `Pod-A`s Local IP `172.31.10.211` from another VM (EC2 Instance). But I am not able to connect from another Pod by some reason.

Comment: Kubernetes cluster VMs and the VM I was able to connect from are on same VPC and share same Security Group. There is something that stops Pod from connecting to another Pod.

Comment: Apparently the pods are not able to reach each other using local IPs.